# Why does the program success depend on that if overloaded constructor is declared?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am writing c++ program. This is Student class:

```
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "Home.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
/*
 * This is default constructor
 */
Student::Student(){

}
/*
 * This is copy constructor
 */
Student::Student(const Student& orig) {
   copy(orig);// invokes deep copy method
}
/*
 * This is a destructor
 */
Student::~Student() {
}

/*
 * This is operator = overloading method.
 * 
 * @param student. It is a reference to student class
 * @return Returns pointer to current class
 */
Student & Student::operator=(Student & student){
   if(this != &student){ // checks if they are referencing the same class.          
      copy(student);
   }
   return *this;
}

/*
 * This is setter
 * 
 * @param x The random integer number
 */
void Student::setValue(int x){
   data = x;
}

/*
 * The getter.
 * 
 * @return Returns integer digit
 */
int Student::getValue(){
   return data; 
}

/*
 * The copy method. It makes a deep copy of a current class.
 * 
 * @param orig. It contains a reference to student class
 */
void Student::copy(const Student &orig){
    if(this != &orig){
    // makes a copy of data member
       data = orig.data;      

    }
}
```

**This is snippet of main method**:

```
Student * array = new Student[objectSize];
    cout << "\nOriginal array of Student type: "; 
    int i = 0; 
    for(int x = objectSize; x > 0; x--){
      array[i].setValue(x);

      cout << array[i] << " "; // prints the contents of original Student type array
       i++;
    }

    defaultObject.addition(array, objectSize); // invokes function to sort array of Student type
```

This is header file:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef STUDENT_HPP
#define STUDENT_HPP

class Student {

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Student& study){// overloads << operator for Student class      
        os << study.data; // the data you output       
    return os; 
   }
public:  
    Student(); // default constructor
   // Student(int data);// overloaded constructor
    Student(const Student& orig);// copy constructor
    virtual ~Student();// destructor
    Student & operator=(Student& student); // overloads = operator
    void setValue(int x);// setter
    int getValue();// getter
    void copy(const Student &orig);// copy method


    friend bool operator> (Student &first, Student &second){// overloads greater operator
       return first.data > second.data;
   }    

private:
    int data;// data member for storing Student's class contents
};

#endif  /* STUDENT_HPP */
```

The problem is that when I comment this line `Student(int data);` in header file the program throws this error:

```
Student.hpp: In function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)':
In file included from Student.cpp:12:
Student.hpp:21: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'os << study->Student::data'
Student.hpp:20: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Student.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

In fact that overloaded constructor at Student.cpp file is not defined, but if declaration is there the program on NetBeans works, though on Linux terminal it throws the mentioned error.

Comment: Please provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) that exhibits your problem. Make it as short as possible.

Comment: This is a short version.

Comment: @ucas : Short, but not self-contained. Where is `main`?

Comment: There is given a short version of the main method (main part).

Comment: @ucas: No, it is not. There should be no need for `setValue`, `getValue`, `copy`, etc. in your code. Do you really need those to exhibit your problem? Do you need the loop in main? Wouldn't a simple `Student s; std::cout << s;` suffice?

Comment: I am creating an array of Student type. I am using setter to pass the value to the Student class. Then I pass that array of Students to sort it out. Copy method is needed to make  a deep copy of  a class.

Comment: @ucas: *Do you need to do that to trigger the compiler error?*

Comment: This is my assignment, I need a array of class type, then pass it to implemented sort method and sort the contents out. And finally print the results.

Comment: @ucas - the problem is it failing to compile if the `Student(int)` constructor is missing. The question is though, to show this problem to us here do you also need to show us the `setValue`, `getValue` etc.? I suspect not.

Comment: Can you show which standard headers you are including?

Comment: ¤ Currently the code shown does not match the compiler's diagnostic. Reproduce the error in a small program and present that program *unchanged*. Some general advice: (1) preferentially use `std::vector` and other standard library containers instead of raw arrays and pointers; (2) don't express copy construction in terms of assignment, instead express assignment in terms of copy construction (look up the "swap idiom"); (3) when you're talking about "deep copying" chances are you need a destructor (look up the "rule of three"). Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'os << study->Student::data'
note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&)
```

You are asking it to write an int to the stream.  Note the very short list of possible candidates, the compiler says it only knows how to write a Student to the stream.  That used to be possible before you commented the Student(int) constructor.  That constructor can be used to convert an int to a Student.  That will come to a very poor end at runtime when the stack blows up, but that's beside the point.

You are missing an #include for a header that declares an operator<< that allows an int to be written to the stream.  Not actually sure which one that might be, I don't like streams.  Not an issue, homework questions shouldn't have real answers :)

Comment: It should be in `<ostream>`, which is what should be included if you want to use `std::ostream` (or maybe he just has `<iosfwd>` included, which just forward declares all the templates).

Comment: On NetBeans on Windows this solution works though on Linux command line it throws errors 'Undefined reference to Assessment <int>:: Assessment()'.